# HoloLens polygon rendering with mesh

Tags: hololens

I work on a HoloLens application and i want to render some simple polygons. Each polygon marks a restricted area.

I used a mesh to solve this task, at the unity player it works fine but on HoloLens it doesn't display the mesh. Does the HoloLens ignore the mesh because of the spatial mapping or have anybody an idea for this problem?

```
        Vector3[] AllVertices = polygonCoordinates.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < AllVertices.Length-3; i = i + 2)
        {
            GameObject polygonGameObject = new GameObject("Polygon");
            Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
            polygonGameObject.transform.SetParent(polygonContainer.transform, true);
            MeshFilter meshFilter = (MeshFilter)polygonGameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));

            //Styles for Mesh
            MeshRenderer renderer = polygonGameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer)) as MeshRenderer;
            renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find("Particles/Additive");
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            tex.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.red);
            tex.Apply();
            renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
            renderer.material.color = Color.red;

            Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4];
            vertices[0] = AllVertices[i];
            vertices[1] = AllVertices[i+1];
            vertices[2] = AllVertices[i+2];
            vertices[3] = AllVertices[i+3];
            mesh.vertices = vertices;

            int[] tri = new int[6];
            //Upper triangle
            tri[0] = 0;
            tri[1] = 1;
            tri[2] = 2;

            //Lower triangle  
            tri[3] = 2;
            tri[4] = 1;
            tri[5] = 3;
            mesh.triangles = tri;

            //Normals for nice rendering
            Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[4];
            normals[0] = -Vector3.forward;
            normals[1] = -Vector3.forward;
            normals[2] = -Vector3.forward;
            normals[3] = -Vector3.forward;
            mesh.normals = normals;

            //For texture
            Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[4];
            uv[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
            uv[1] = new Vector2(1, 0);
            uv[2] = new Vector2(0, 1);
            uv[3] = new Vector2(1, 1);
            mesh.uv = uv;
            mesh.RecalculateNormals();

            meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
            GameObject.Instantiate(polygonGameObject);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this problem to the HoloLens forum too and we solved my problem.

I repost the correct answer here:

"Shader.Find is failing in your deployed project because Particles/Additive probably isn't getting included in the build (though it's there when you run from the editor). Try adding a Resources folder under Assets and putting your Additive shader there. Any files in Resources should be guaranteed to be included in your build. Then call Assets/Resources with your Find method instead of Particles/Additive."